# Trying to identify ways to speed up code for transitioning data cleaning to R using tidyverse

Tags: r, validation, dplyr

I am helping some colleagues update their data validation/cleaning and reporting (will help them move to RMarkdown eventually) to help minimize manual steps. I am looking for ways to help speed up the process to help them with their data cleaning.

The file I am currently looking at has about 500 columns and 150,000 rows, though that may be variable between data collection periods.

For example, part of their recoding involves knowing the number of columns associated with a racial/ethnic group, counting the number of responses across all the columns of the group and setting a value to missing if the sum of the affirmative columns matches the total possible columns for the group. The idea being that someone just checked everything to be done and it is invalid data.

Other times another value (say othval - a placeholder that may represent many created variables needed for transformation) may be developed and then used to modify other columns.

Additional issues - the number of columns under a particular group may change in any given year if a category is added or deleted, so manually identifying each column name should be avoided as much as possible.

Right now I have the process below, which works but it runs incredibly slow due to the rowwise nature of the calculations. And that's just one set of variables I am testing it on. This must occur across multiple variables for race as well as for other variables not listed here. So this will only get more added to address the various conditions.

I have provided an example code below that assumes that Asian race is represented by the cluster of var5* columns to outline an example.

All columns have the same prefix as well ("var" is universal for every field in the original data)

Edit:I am doing a couple quick examples of specific sets and then passing this along to people *new* to R, in further discussions with them they want something accessible, so I am trying to stick with a tidy approach and in a more familiar tabular format versus reshaping the data (a concept not familiar to them). Based on their explanation, there are also processes that will require work by ID and group but I don't work with the data other than a small snippet they're having me work on as an example.

Any suggestions for how to speed up the process with all of the above in mind?

```
dat <- data %>%  
       mutate(cntAsian = ncol(across(matches("^var5\\D.*$"))) # need the count to get the max columns of the set
       ) %>%  
       group_by(ID) %>% 
       mutate(ChkAsian = rowSums(pick(matches("^var5\\D.*$")), na.rm = T), # count sum of affirmative values present (1)
       across(matches("^var5\\D.*$"), ~ case_when(ChkAsian == cntAsian ~ 9999, TRUE ~ .x)) # if max columns matches max checkboxes, set to 9999 for example
)
```

Edit: I was able to get them to provide a very simple quick approximation of layout for this particular scenario. `othval` is a catchall which may require various permutations and additional coding.

| id | var5a | var5b | var5c | var5d | othval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |

Comment: I suspect it will be more efficient to reshape your data into longer form so you can avoid rowwise calculations. It'll be hard to offer any more concrete advice unless you can create some sort of toy example data that demonstrates the issue on a small scale.

Comment: I think you don't need the `group_by(ID)` for the `rowSums`.  Try it without the grouping

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you. That might be the approach I take. I will see how a long transformation does and if it bogs things down. Sadly, the nature of the data does not allow me to create a toy set which is one of the big barriers for discussing externally.

Comment: @akrun Thanks! for this particular instance that works. I will see if that also applies to other stuff which would be great if it is not necessary to group.

Comment: @pophealth I meant this only because of the nature of the `rowSums` function.  It won't apply if you are doing a mean or sum of the column by group

Comment: "the nature of the data does not allow me to create a toy set":  I doubt this. For instance, I think I am getting the expected results using this with your code: `data.frame(ID = 1:2, col1 = "a", var5.one = TRUE, var5.two = c(TRUE, FALSE))`. But you will be in a better position to articulate the salient data features you want the code to accommodate.

Comment: @akrun Yep, I understood your context. I am barely scratching the surface of their stuff and hopefully will mostly get something with a few workable examples for them to start with and help when needed but trying to make it as smooth as possible so they don't run screaming.

Comment: @JonSpring More that this is just a few quick examples for them to kind of start learning. So, I have barely scratched the surface of their work and it is not within my time or scope to build something with more detailed examples that might arise.. I am trying to find something more complicated (as I understand it from their explanation) as a coding example to help replace some of their many lines of code but I haven't gone through their three files with 1000s of lines of code each because I have other stuff I am working on. This is to get them going on their own and will support as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck helping your colleagues.

In general, R is more performant for problems where calculations are run vertically across rows instead of horizontally across columns.

Here I reshape longer using `tidyr::pivot_longer` and then do the calculations as groups. For data with many groups like this, `data.table` will generally be much faster if more speed is worth the upfront work to update the syntax.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

n = 10000 # make it even for simplicity
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:n, col1 = "a", var5.one = TRUE, var5.two = c(TRUE, FALSE))

a <- bench::mark(
  orig = df %>%
    mutate(cntAsian = ncol(across(matches("^var5\\D.*$")))) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(ChkAsian = rowSums(pick(matches("^var5\\D.*$")), na.rm = T), 
           across(matches("^var5\\D.*$"), ~case_when(ChkAsian == cntAsian ~ 9999, TRUE ~ .x))),
  pivot = df %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with("var5")) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(cntAsian = as.integer(n()), ChkAsian = as.numeric(sum(value))) %>%
    mutate(value = if_else(cntAsian == ChkAsian, 9999, as.numeric(value))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
    select(ID, col1, var5.one, var5.two, cntAsian, ChkAsian)
)
```

Results for n = 10k:

- exact same output
- 26x faster
- 49x lower memory usage

For n = 150k, the `pivot` approach took about 25 seconds, which isn't great but I presume faster than the original code. There's probably a lot more performance that could be squeezed out using `data.table`, `collapse`, `arrow`, or `duckdb` variations.

---

```
a
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                  memory     time       gc      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                  <list>     <list>     <list>  
1 orig         44.55s   44.55s    0.0224     882MB     2.83     1   126     44.55s <gropd_df [10,000 × 6]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
2 pivot         1.68s    1.68s    0.594       18MB     2.97     1     5      1.68s <gropd_df [10,000 × 6]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```